# View SQL generated by Entity Framework version 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

How can I view the complete sql query generated by Entity Framework (version 5)? I can view it using

```
query.ToString()
```

but I don't get all the parameters with it.  I get a lot of variables like @p_linq_0.

Comment: Have you put `.EnableSensitiveDataLogging()` on the end of your `UseSqlServer` call in startup? Anlso note that inspecting your queryable's `.DebugView` gives more info than ToString()

Comment: If you can do `query.ToString()` you are in EF classic. I added the tag. Please choose another tag if you don't agree.

Comment: In newer versions see https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2020/01/12/toquerystring/

Answer (score 0):

You can log the SQL queries in your Console Output window by using [`EnableSensitiveDataLogging`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.enablesensitivedatalogging?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontextoptionsbuilder-enablesensitivedatalogging(system-boolean)) EnableSensitiveDataLogging also log more details when an exception occurs in EF

```
 public ApplicationDbContext CreateContext()
        => new ApplicationDbContext(
            new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .UseSqlServer(Configuration["TestDBConnection"])
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .Options);
```

From EF Core 5.0 onwards you can also use the [`LogTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.logto?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontextoptionsbuilder-logto(system-action((system-string))-system-func((microsoft-extensions-logging-eventid-microsoft-extensions-logging-loglevel-system-boolean))-system-nullable((microsoft-entityframeworkcore-diagnostics-dbcontextloggeroptions)))) method which takes an Action delegate as a parameter and enables you to log into the Console or to a file, or to a NoSQL database for example

```
     public ApplicationDbContext CreateContext()
        => new ApplicationDbContext(
            new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .UseSqlServer(Configuration["TestDBConnection"])
                .LogTo(Console.WriteLine)
                .Options);
```